# Fuzzy search and stopwords in Solr

Tags: solr, stop-words, solr-search

I want to use fuzzy search, so I append `~1` for each term in the query, for example the initial query is `"name:the matrix"`, so after appending `~1`, the query is `"name:the~1 matrix~1"`.

Everything works, except stopwords, now it finds also the documents with the name `"the sun"`

The `name` field type is

```
<fieldType name="managed_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="false">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ManagedStopFilterFactory" managed="english" />
    <filter class="solr.ManagedSynonymGraphFilterFactory" managed="english" />
    <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory"/> <!-- required on index analyzers after graph filters -->
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ManagedStopFilterFactory" managed="english" />
    <filter class="solr.ManagedSynonymGraphFilterFactory" managed="english" />
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

How to configure that fuzzy search should be applied to stopwords?

Comment: what id the defination of fieldtype for your field?

Comment: Also be aware that your query searches for `the` in the `name` field, and `matrix` in the default search field (not usually `name`).

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti I've updated the question